# List commands enabled by package

Tags: apt, bash, package-management

It has happened a few times that I installed a tool through apt or by downloading a package, but I cannot figure out what the command is to use the new software. For instance, I recently installed openmcdf. I tried the command openmcdf to run the newly installed software, but of course that was not the right command. The right command as it turns out was structuredstorageexplorer which I found after much searching on the internet. So is there a tool for displaying the commands that have been enabled by installing a package? Something like:

```
list-programs-from-package openmcdf
```

Comment: You mean like https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/openmcdf/filelist? That's far from a good solution, but you could `wget` this: `wget -qO- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/openmcdf/filelist | sed '/\/usr\/bin/!d;s_[^/]*/_/_'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `dpkg -L $package | grep "usr/bin"` to see all the binaries or scripts that should appear in your `$PATH` to be executed by a normal user.

Some packages may install binaries in other locations which are not meant to be executed by normal users, though.

Comment: You meant `grep /usr/bin/`, didn't you? Unfortunately this approach doesn't work for e.g. `libreoffice` or `transmission`.

Comment: Look at `dpkg -L libreoffice` - no executables in that package, but see `dpkg -l libreoffice\* | grep -E '^ii'`. I don't have `transmission` installed, but it's probably the same thing.

Comment: Use `dpkg -L $package | less` and look at ALL the files installed by the package. Executables stored in `/bin`,`/usr/bin`,`/usr/local/bin`, or anywhere else , `man` pages, `.desktop` files, startup files in `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d`, etc, etc.

Comment: @dessert Sure it does. The problem with libreoffice is that it's many packages. Likewise, transmission has multiple packages, for different UI versions. It works if you know the package name, which is what the question was about.

Comment: @waltinator Debian packages shouldn't install to /usr/local/bin. If one does, it's broken. Likewise, anything in /bin/ should only be done in core system packages installed by default. The question also wasn't about man pages, desktop files, or system services registering with some service management service (SYSV, systemd, upstart,  etc…).